# JS - Convert a "Europe/Berlin"-Date into a UTC-Timestamp

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone

Inside my Docker-Container, which has the timezone `Etc/UTC`, I need to convert a Date-String which represents a Date in `Europe/Berlin`-timezone into a UTC timestamp.

So lets say the `Europe/Berlin`-Date is `2022-04-20T00:00:00`.

Now the UTC-Timestamp should be equivalent to `2022-04-19T22:00:00`.

But when I do

```
console.log(new Date("2022-04-20").getTime())
```

I get `1650412800000` which is equivalent to `2022-04-20T02:00:00` in `Europe/Berlin`-timezone.

How would I do this?

Edit:

I tried various libs, but still cant get that managed

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon")


var f = DateTime.fromISO("2022-04-20").setZone('Europe/Berlin').toUTC()
console.log(f)
```

also the equivalent stamp in  `f` is `2022-04-20T02:00:00` :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to convert a Date-String which represents a Date in Europe/Berlin-timezone into a UTC timestamp.

Fundamentally, a date-only value cannot be converted into a timestamp, unless you arbitrarily associate a *time* with that date.  It sounds like you meant to use midnight local time (00:00+02:00) but instead you are seeing midnight UTC (00:00Z).

This is due to how you are constructing the `Date` object.  You specify `new Date("2022-04-20")`, which according to [the ECMASCript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse) will be treated as midnight UTC.  The spec says:

> ... When the UTC offset representation is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.

Yes, this is inconsistent with ISO 8601, and that has been discussed ad nauseum.

To solve this problem, append `T00:00` to your input string, so that you are specifically asking for local time. In other words, `new Date("2022-04-20T00:00")`.

That said, if you need it to not be "local time"  but *exactly* `Europe/Berlin`, then yes - you'll need to use a library.  In luxon, it's like this:

```
DateTime.fromISO('2022-04-20T00:00', {zone: 'Europe/Berlin'}).toUTC()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) .. As the script runs inside a docker container and a docker-container does not inherit the host's timezone, it is always `ETC/UTC` by default, the solution was really to use luxon.